# What does 'live it for the best good of others mean exactly?

Tags: meaning

we were sent into this world for a wise and good purpose, and must do our duties without repining, take our life as we might find it, **live it for the best good of others**, and never mind about the results; they were not our affair.

from *A dog's tale* by Mark Twain

Comment: This is not a well-formed sentence and I don't think there's much value in examining it- except possibly to correct it.

Comment: Mark Twain, huh?  Well, I still don't like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One meaning of good as a noun is

> profit or advantage; worth; benefit

from this [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/good?s=t).

If I were to substitute the word *good* by *benefit*, for example, it will be:

> live it for the best benefit of others

which is also correct.

Comment: And the use of 'live' as a transitive verb allows only a very small set of direct objects: cognate (live my life for the good of others) and hyponymic (/ elliptic) (he is living a lie).